# how do I send files with an discord bot py

Tags: discord.py

I m trying to send a file with my bot but if I search how to do this I alway get somthing I cant use because I m using

@client.tree.command and Interaction
and not @bot.command and ctx

I tried:

```
@client.tree.command()
async def download(interaction: discord.Interaction,link:str):
        await interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=True)
        link1 = link
        yt = YouTube(link1)
        yd = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
        yd.download("C:\\Users\\phili\\OneDrive\\code\\discord bot")
        await interaction.followup.send(file=f"{yd.title}.mp4")
```

I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 862, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\phili\OneDrive\code\discord bot\main.py", line 512, in download
    await interaction.followup.send(file=f"{yd.title}.mp4")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\webhook\async_.py", line 1706, in send
    params = handle_message_parameters(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 241, in handle_message_parameters
    attachments_payload.append(attachment.to_dict())
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1242, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 887, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 880, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
```

Answer (score 0):

In discord.py, the `file` argument (for any [Messageable](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=send#discord.abc.Messageable.send)) is expected to be an instance of the [File](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20file#discord.File) class. So to send a locally saved file or downloaded file, you need to use the `File` class constructor.

```py
file = discord.File("exact/path/to/the/file.mp4")
await interaction.followup.send(file=file)
```

Its first argument expects to be a `path` to the file or a `file-like` object.